# iMessage frozen/crashing

Tags: ipod-touch, messages

I have an iPod Touch 5th gen and I sent a really long emoji message to my friend and both our iPods froze! Now everytime I try to open it, it goes to the conversation menu, freezes for about 10 seconds, then crashes back to home screen.

I tried:

- Restart
- Long Restart
- Double clicking home and closing all recently used apps
- Turning off imessage then turning it back on and logging in
- Going to contacts then clicking to iMessage them

Nothing works.

Answer (score 2):

I just had the same problem. After seething my iPad and restoring it through icloud I still wouldn't work but what did work was going to a random contact and clicking send message, it opens iMessage right up and I was able to delete my conversation that was causing the problem!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are stuck resetting, then restoring your iPod.

1. Turn off iMessage. The goal is that in the software restore, iMessages won't come back. This is the part that is pretty much up to you. You could leave it on and restore, and hope for the best, or turn it off with hopes that iMessages are cleared.
2. [Backup your device](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1766) - preferably [to iCloud](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4859).
3. Go to Settings.app > General > Reset > Erase All Content and Settings.

   - IMPORTANT: Make sure you have at least one good backup, whether iCloud or iTunes. If you backup for the first time to iCloud just then, it may take awhile. It may take 1-4 hours and maybe more.
4. After the device has been reset, restore the data (refer to the linked articles above).

The goal is that the iMessages won't be restored. However, it is very possible they *will* be. If the Messages app continues to freeze your last resort may be to start the device over (reset without restoring). **Note:** if it comes to that all your app data (game scores and such) will be lost.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and found this solution online.  Worked for me: {You can press on the contacts app, press a contact, and then press the message button. Then you will be taken into iMessage and you can text again!}

Once in, delete the culprit message and all should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Resetting* but just wanted to let you know that it's easy to fix

Comment: Welcome to the site. Can you please explain a bit more what you did to fix this issues? Knowing that it is easy to fix is great, but actually knowing the fix would be preferable!

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem here on my iPad mini, here is how to fix it:

- Keep turning iMessage off and on
- Then shut down your iPad by holding the power off button
- Wait for ten minutes
- Turn it back on by holding the off button
- Wait until the home screen will show up
- Now go to settings and turn off Facetime, iMessage, WiFi
- Go to airplane Mode and turn that on
- Shut down ur iPad by holding the off button
- Wait for fifteen minutes
- Restart the iPad by holding the power button
- Now turn off airplane mode
- Turn on FaceTime and iMessage and Internet/wifi
- Go to the iMessage icon
- Click edit at the top left corner
- There will be red circles with minuses on them
- Click the red circle by the messages u sent to ur friend
- Now click delete
- iMessage will not freeze again

Comment: It would help a lot if you could rewrite your answer so that it becomes more clear on the steps.

Answer (score 0):

My iPod kept shuting down and it wouldn't open the iMessages app. (My friend tryed sending me a photo that you can't have on your iPod only on your iPhone) So I tryed shutting off iMessages but it did nothing I went to a contact that I never messages and pressed send message and you can click cancel and delet it from there.

Hope this was helpful

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me:
If you have Siri (like I do on my iPad) I told Siri to send a simple "hi" message to one of my contacts and when they replied, I just opened iMessage and it worked fine. I just had to delete the conversation that gave me the crash with the LONG emoji message. Hope this helps!! (:

Answer (score -1):

Switch your iPad off,for 10 seconds switch it back on go in to contacts click on any contact (that's not the one iMessage crashed whilst texting) and click send message and it will work and iMessage will work again.
It worked for me and I hope it works for you.

An alternate solution is to go into contacts, choose a random contact that's not the one that crashes, then it will take you into iMessage, then press messages in the top left corner, and then edit in the left corner, then select the message that is crashing, delete it, then re-add the contact.

Comment: a) This question isn't about an iPad, and b) The asker clearly states he has tried a long restart.