# iMessage crashes upon opening (Cannot text)

Tags: iphone, messages, crash

Whenever I open my iMessage on my iPhone it crashes.  Someone sent a message that contained like 5000 of these (and I'm not even exaggerating) that's about 50000 characters.

```
 ( ͡° ͜ʖ ͡° )
```

Please help me delete this group message without going on my iPhone. (I have a windows PC with iTunes.)

Comment: Have you tried the fixes listed in [this older StackExchange thread](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/79814/imessage-frozen-crashing)? In particular, receiving or sending another text to get Messages "off" the offending text has reportedly worked for this kind of problem in the past.

Comment: @Merlin the difference is that this is not an emoji and it is Unicode characters. Unicode and ASCII are two different things

Comment: @Merlin and I also tried everything he said before. The problem is fixed now. I just had to restore a backup of my phone that was on my computer from a week ago.

Comment: I understand that Unicode and ASCII are different, but the fixes likely work for the same reason: "distracting" Messages from attempting to load or display the offending content. Glad you could work around it though!